# Android: Compile data file into app folder

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app, which needs to read a data file, so it can process and display it. This files will be updated from a remote location from time to time.

I have a working code to download this file from a remote location after installation, read it, then write it into the `files` folder of the app. I also know that I can place it into the `res/raw` folder and perform the same read->write operation. Both options work, I don't need help regarding these.

But I would like to omit these options if possible, and place this data file into the `files` folder during development and compile it into the apk.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: `I also know that I can place it into the res/raw folder and perform the same read->write operation. ` No. The res resource is read only.

Comment: `place this data file into the files folder during development and compile it into the apk.` I dont know about a files folder. The usual place is res/raw or assets. Both will be compiled in the apk. Both are read only at runtime. So you would copy the file at first start to the file system where you can edit it.

Comment: Why don't you store the data in res/raw (like you have indicated). Then, when the app is run, check whether or not its running for the first time, in which case you can copy the files from raw to files. And like @blackapps has pointed out, res is read only. And you cant have files in the files (internal) folder at installation.

Comment: @blackapps I meant from `res/raw` into `files`.

Comment: @Kasalwe Because I think it's a redundant step to copy a file from one folder to the other, IF I can place it right where I want it. I will go with this solution, if my request is not possible, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I don't think it's redundant. It's like you have an app that should ship with some data (Because you want it to work without first having to download the initial data). The approach of putting a default file in res or assets and then copying it to internal memory on first run isn't a bad idea. You only copy when the files folder is empty (first run - a preference can be set to avoid duplicated efforts). **Your app cant ship with files in the files folder**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a working code to download this file from a remote location after installation, read it, then write it into the `files` folder of the app.

I am going to guess that by "the `files` folder", you are referring to something like `getFilesDir()`.

> Because I think it's a redundant step to copy a file from one folder to the other, IF I can place it right where I want it.

Sorry, that is not an option.

Comment: @Kasalwe replied first. If he does not post his comment as an answer, I will accept yours. Thanks for the feedback.